# If table contains something then do something

Tags: cypress

How can I code: If table contains some text then do something.
I tried it with contains but that throws me error if table does not contains.

```
if(cy.get(tableCode).contains('td', value)){
        cy.get(tableCode).contains('td', value).click()
    }else{
        cy.reload()
    }
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Please post the code you tried.

Answer (score 3):

The proper way to us jQuery `:contains()` would be

```js
cy.get(tableCode).then($table => {
  const $cell = $table.find('td:contains(value)')
  if ($cell.length) {
    $cell.click()
  } else {
    cy.reload()
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Jquery length](https://api.jquery.com/length/) method to check if the element is present in the table or not -

```
cy.get('tableCode').then(($ele) => {
    if ($ele.find('td').contains('value').length > 0) {
        //Element found
        cy.wrap($ele).find('td').contains('value').click()
    }
    else {
        //Element not found
        cy.reload()
    }
})
```